# Sublime Text set custom goto symbols

Tags: sublimetext2, shortcut

I am a big fan of ST2, and have been finding oodles of tricks to code/type faster.

One thing that I would like to know is if it is possible to create custom symbols for things like code blocks, include segments, and other bookmarks for goodies in your file.

For example:
I want to quickly include a standard C lib via (inc, tab). Is there a way for me to create a section where I keep all my standard lib includes (i.e: @CSTDLIB) and use the functionality of goto-> symbol (ctrl+r) to skip straight to this segment from anywhere in my file?

I tried looking to see if there was some sort of special handler to place in a comment that would recognise it as a "bookmark" but couldnt really find anything.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so I'm answering for the latest ST3. Pretty sure this was possible with older versions as well.

The builtin C/C++ syntax definitions support a special formatting for comments in the following form:

```
// =jump target=
```

The string "jump target" will then be listed in the symbol list for `ctrl+r`. Unfortunately that only works if the `//` is at the beginning of the line. But we can fix that.

Install `Package​Resource​Viewer`, then from the command palette use `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`->`C++`->`C.sublime-syntax`.

In this file it says:

```
- match: ^// =(\s*.*?)\s*=\s*$\n?
  scope: comment.line.banner.c
  captures:
    1: meta.toc-list.banner.line.c
```

Now remove the `^` in front of the regexp, save the file. Now you can enter comments `// =jump target=` anywhere, and jump there with `ctrl+r`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut for making bookmarks anywhere in your file, and walk through these bookmarks by <kbd>F2</kbd> button. To remove bookmark, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> again in the line which you want to exclude from bookmarks.
If it isn't so, and this functionality doesn't cover your requirements, please specify more detailed use case.

Hope it will be useful to you

Comment: This is on the right track, but not quite what I'm after. I'm after more of a list-based approach. For example, where hitting f2 would provide an ordered list you could search literally. Much like you can jump to method declarations.